# Замедление рисования при изменении размера окна в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, рисование

В моей программе реализуется моделирование математического маятника. При изменении размера виджета, в котором непосредственно происходит отрисовка колебаний, период колебаний изменятся. Т.е. при увеличении размера окна период скорость колебаний уменьшается. Что необходимо сделать, чтобы при изменении размеров виджета скорость рисования не менялось?

```
    void mainWidgetClass::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    double x, y;

    double a = lengthOfThread/200;
    QPainter painter(this); //создание исполнителя рисования

    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 10)); // Рисование начальной точки

    painter.drawPoint(QPoint(this->width()/2, this->height()/4));

    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 1));

    phi = initialAmplitude*cos(cyclicFrequency*time + initialPhase);

    x = this->width()/2 + lengthOfThread*sin(phi)/a;
    y = this->height()/4 + lengthOfThread*cos(phi)/a;



    painter.drawLine(QPointF(this->width()/2, this->height()/4), QPointF(x, y));
}
```

Comment: Скорость меняется после того, как вы поменяли размер окна или в процессе изменения окна (а после изменения она остаётся прежней)? Откуда берётся `time`? Как вы вызываете `paintEvent`? В случае если скорость движения меняется исключительно во время расширения окна, то, полагаю, вам нужно получать значение `time` в самом `paintEvent`.

Comment: Скорость меняется после того, как меняется размер окна. Допустим, при переключении в полноэкранный режим колебания становятся совсем медленными. time это переменная, отвечающая за время, она изменятся при срабатывании таймера, также при срабатывании таймера обновляется виджет, на котором всё рисуется с помощью метода update(). paintEvent вызывается при создании виджета и при вызове метода update() при срабатывании таймера

Comment: Я полагаю, что положение маятника зависит от значения переменной time, которая, как Вы полагаете, изменяется синхронно с часами. Но на самом деле Вы используете таймер, а он, будучи запущенным в одном потоке с графикой, вовсе не гарантирует, что будет срабатывать через фиксированный промежуток времени. Вам нужно либо синхронизировать значение переменной time с текущим машинным временем, либо разделить работу с графикой и таймером в разных потоках. Но из моего опыта скажу, что часы, реализованные на таймере, всегда накапливают отставание.